# Finding generalized term.

Tags: sequences-and-series

A sequence is defined as follows:

First term, $x_1 = 1$.

For further terms,

$x_{r+1} = x_{r} + m$ , if $x_r <=(n-m)  $

$x_{r+1} = x_{r} -(n-m) $ , otherwise.

$0 <= m <= n$ where n,m are integers.

> I am interested in finding, for what value of 'r', does 1 occur again? Is it possible to do so without constructing the sequence term by term ?

For example, for n=4, m=2 , the sequence is : 1,3,1. So r=3.

Comment: Obviously, it is ${n\over GCD(m,n-m)}+1$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin . Thanks. That looks correct. But can you please tell how do you arrive at that ? It is not obvious to me. Also, may be you can add that as an answer rather than comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we go up by $m$ and down by $n-m$ till we arrive at zero; when that might be? The sum of all "up" steps (which is a multiple of $m$) must be equal to the sum of all "down" steps (which is a multiple of $n-m$). Clearly, that sum must be $LCM(m,n-m)$, which gives us $LCM(m,n-m)\over m$ "up" steps and $LCM(m,n-m)\over n-m$ "down" steps. Now what is an LCM of two numbers? It is their product divided by their GCD. So the total number of steps is ${LCM(m,n-m)\over m}+{LCM(m,n-m)\over n-m}={n-m\over GCD(m,n-m)}+{m\over GCD(m,n-m)}={n\over GCD(m,n-m)}$. BTW, we may simplify a little bit more: it is also ${n\over GCD(n,m)}$. That's it.